# Find $P(X<3)$ and $E(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution

I am a little confused with finding $P(X<3)$ and $E(X)$. I ask this question before but no one answer. Here, $A$, $B$, $C$ are Poisson random variables with parameters $2.6$, $3$, and $3.4$, respectively. Let $X$ be the number of errors typed in a manuscript. Each of three typists $A$, $B$, $C$ are equally likely to type the manuscript with error rates given. For the

$E(X)=\frac{1}{3}(2.6+3.4+3)=3$

but I am not sure. I am, also, having problems understanding $P(X<3)$. I am getting:

$\begin{align*}P(X<3) &= \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(e^{-3.4}\frac{3.4^2}{2!}+e^{-2.6}\frac{2.6^2}{2!}+e^{-3}\frac{3^2}{2!}\right)\\&+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(e^{-3.4}\frac{3.4^1}{1!}+e^{-2.6}\frac{2.6^1}{1!}+e^{-3}\frac{3^1}{1!}\right)\\&+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(e^{-3.4}\frac{3.4^0}{0!}+e^{-2.6}\frac{2.6^0}{0!}+e^{-3}\frac{3^0}{0!}\right)\\&=0.42711.\end{align*}$

but I feel is wrong. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: If you choose one typist at random, each with probability $1/3$ of being chosen, then certain conclusions follow.

But are you proposing to choose one typist at random, each with probability $1/3$ of being chosen? Your question is completely unclear about that. You need to state the problem clearly. If that is what you meant, then the answer you propose is right.

On the other hand, if all three will type the whole document, then the expected number of errors in their work will be the sum of the three expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the law of Total Probability.

Recall that $E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X = k)$. We write :
$$
P(X = k) = P(X = k \mid A)P(A) + P(X = k \mid B)P(B) + P(X = k \mid C) P(C)
$$

where $P(X = k \mid A)$ is the probability that $A$ makes exactly $k$ errors (similarly for $B,C$) and $P(A)$ is the probability that $A$ is chosen to type (similarly $B,C$).

From here, we also get :
\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k[ P(X = k \mid A)P(A) + P(X = k \mid B)P(B) + P(X = k \mid C)P(C)]
\\ &= \frac 13\sum_{k=1}^\infty k[P(X = k \mid A) + P(X = k\mid B) +P(X = k\mid C)]
\\ &= \frac 13\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X = k\mid A) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X = k\mid B)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X = k\mid C)\right)
\\ &= \frac 13\left(E[X \mid A] + E[X\mid B] + E[X \mid C]\right) 
\\ &= \frac 13(2.6+3.4+3) = 3
\end{align}

What you've done for the second part is also correct and justified by :
$$
P(X < 3) = P(X =0) + P(X = 1) + P(X = 2) \\ = \sum_{i=0}^2 P(X = i | A)P(A) + P(X = i|B)P(B) + P(X = i|C)P(C) 
$$

Which is exactly what you've computed above! I've checked the formulas and the long expression seems fine. If you are finding a mistake after checking with a friend / textbook, check the calculations.

EDIT : Calculations are $\color{blue}{\mathrm{fine!}}$

Comment: This is not Bayes rule, it is [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: Edited, was checking for that just now.

Comment: What about for for $E[X^2]$ I am assuming is almost the same but with $k^2$, right?

Comment: Yep, so you would use the law of total probability to see that the answer is one third of the sum of the individual sqaure expectations, which can be calculated easily for the Poisson.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are correct.  Let $T_A$, $T_B$, $T_C$ be the events that the manuscript is typed by $A, B, C$ respectively.
The conditional distribution of $X$ given $T_A$ is Poisson with parameter $2.6$, and similarly for $T_B$ and $T_C$ with parameters $3$ and $3.4$.  Since $T_A$, $T_B$ and $T_C$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive,

$$ \mathbb E[X] = \mathbb P(T_A) \mathbb E[X\mid T_A] + 
\mathbb P(T_B) \mathbb E[X\mid T_B] +  \mathbb P(T_C) \mathbb E[X\mid T_C]$$

Similarly

$$ \mathbb P(X < 3) = \mathbb P(T_A) \mathbb P(X < 3 \mid T_A) + \mathbb P(T_B) \mathbb P(X < 3 \mid T_B) + \mathbb P(T_C) \mathbb P(X < 3 \mid T_C) $$